# XBlog Startup Templates

Tags: module

I'm evaluating the xblog module. Having an example to fallback to [here](https://xcentium.com/blog) was nice but I'd like to see it up and running in my local instance. I've noticed a few hardcoded references to things like `/sitecore/templates/XBlog/Page` which is in `BlogCreator`. Are there any starter template items/renderings for this module? I searched through the repo for `*.item`, `*.yml` and `*.zip` files hoping for some serialized items or a package but didn't find any. Am I missing something like that or is the expectation that items will be created from scratch when using this module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XBlog is a Sitecore marketplace module and you can download it from this link - https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/XBlog.aspx?sc_lang=en based on the Sitecore version you are using. You just need to extract the package file to see the Sitecore items.

There is also a document on the same link, which will provide you all the steps to install and configure the module.

From the [repo](https://github.com/XCentium/XBlog) you can download the code base but it will not have the Sitecore items/renderings if you want to sync this with your VS solution, you can simply sync using Unicorn or TDS after installing the package.

For the content, yes you need to create it from scratch.